# How can I see the FK from Oracle DB? (Oracle 18c)

Tags: oracle

I created a SQL. It show me an error below this.

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYDBS.FK31_1)

I want to see this **FK31_1**. Is it possible to run **SQL** to get it?

Please let me know how to do that.

And I give you my love to seeing this question :)

Comment: You can query `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` view, something like `select * from ALL_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK31_1'` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022

Comment: It matches awesome exactly what I was looking for!!
I am glad to your answer! Thank you!!

Comment: Don't you have a tool? Oracle SQL Developer is free, and getting information on a table, constraint, whatever is usually just one or two clicks.

Comment: My machine does not contain the tool. However, I can run SQL from the Oracle APEX development environment." I will ask for the admin to install the "Oracle SQL Developer" . Thanks for your good information for me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle provides plenty *metadata* views, which start from `ALL_`, `USER_` and `DBA_`. In our case we wants [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022) which you can query as

```
select *
  from ALL_CONSTRAINTS
 where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK31_1'
```

**Edit:** As *Jeff Holt* mentioned in the comment below you can try [ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1035.htm) as well:

```
select *
  from ALL_CONS_COLUMNS 
 where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK31_1'
```

Comment: You may want to mention `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` for constraints that don't reveal enough information in the `SEARCH_CONDITION`. Foreign key constraints, what the OP is all about, is a prime example.

Comment: @Jeff Holt: Thank you! You are quite right: in case we want to find out simple foreign key's *table* and *column* `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` can well be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Select from `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` and `DBA_CONS_COLUMNS`, if you have access rights. Otherwise try `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` and `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS`. Join the columns table twice, so as to get the column(s) of the primary or unique key of the parent table combined with the column(s) of the foreign key of the child table:

```
select
  fkc.table_name as child_table,
  fkc.column_name as child_table_col,
  pkc.table_name as parent_table,
  pkc.column_name as parent_table_col
from dba_constraints fk
join dba_cons_columns fkc on fkc.owner = fk.owner
                         and fkc.constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
join dba_cons_columns pkc on pkc.owner = fk.r_owner
                         and pkc.constraint_name = fk.r_constraint_name
                         and pkc.position = fkc.position
where fk.owner = 'MYDBS'
and fk.constraint_name = 'FK31_1'
order by fkc.position;
```

Comment: Thank you so much and thanks for giving me a lovely nice SQL!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the diagram about the DBA-views that contain the FK-information (shows all kinds of constraints (PK,UK,FK,CHECK,NOT-NULL))

[image: The screenshots shows all kinds of constraints (PK,UK,FK,CHECK,NOT-NULL)]